# Viewpager operations triggered on wrong reference

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter

I am having a Viewpager where i am loading data of different categories. I want to show a custom dialog popup whenever user stays on a particular category for 5 seconds or more asking the user if he/she wants to share the content. For that i have used a custom dialog and am hiding/showing based on the condition.

But the problem is, that if i want to open the dialog if the user stays on Viewpager item at position let's say 3, the dialog is opening for the Viewpager item at position 4.

I am not sure why it's referencing the wrong Viewpager item. 
I am including the code of Adapter class for the reference.

### ArticleAdapter.java

```
public class ArticleAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public List<Articles> articlesListChild;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    View rootView;
    View customArticleShareDialog, customImageShareDialog;
    public int counter = 0;
    int contentType = 0;
    int userId;

    public ArticleAdapter(Context context, List<Articles> articlesListChild, int userId) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.articlesListChild = articlesListChild;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return articlesListChild.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;

    public void startTimer() {
        timer = new Timer();
        initializeTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 5*1000, 5*1000);
    }
    private void initializeTimerTask() {
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                switch (contentType) {
                    case 1:
                        showShareDialog("articles");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        showShareDialog("images");
                        break;
                    default :
                        // Do Nothing
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext());
        View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_single_item, null, false);

        final ImageView contentIv, imageContentIv;
        final TextView sharingTextTv;
        final LinearLayout articleShareBtn, articlesLayout, imagesLayout, customArticleShareDialog, customImageShareDialog;

        contentIv = viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.content_iv);
        articleShareBtn = viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.article_share_btn);
        articlesLayout = viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.articles_layout);
        imagesLayout = viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.images_layout);
        imageContentIv = viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.image_content_iv);
        sharingTextTv = viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.sharing_text_tv);
        customArticleShareDialog = viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.articles_share_popup);
        customImageShareDialog = viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.images_share_popup);

        rootView = viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.post_main_cv);
        viewLayout.setTag(rootView);
        articleShareBtn.setTag(rootView);

        // Images
        if (articlesListChild.get(position).getArticleCatId() == 1) {
            articlesLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
            imagesLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
            requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder);
            Glide.with(context)
                    .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                    .load(articlesListChild.get(position).getArticleImage())
                    .into(imageContentIv);
            imageContentIv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            sharingTextTv.setText("Found this image interesting? Share it with your friends.");
            counter = 0;
            startTimer();
        // Articles
        } else if (articlesListChild.get(position).getArticleCatId() == 2){
            RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
            requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder);
            articlesLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(context)
                    .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                    .load(articlesListChild.get(position).getArticleImage())
                    .into(contentIv);
            contentIv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            sharingTextTv.setText("Found this article interesting? Share it with your friends.");
            counter = 0;
            startTimer();
        }
        container.addView(viewLayout, 0);
        return viewLayout;

    }

    public void showShareDialog(String categoryType) {
        if (categoryType.equalsIgnoreCase("articles")) {
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    customArticleShareDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        } else if (categoryType.equalsIgnoreCase("images")) {
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    customImageShareDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

### ArticleActivity.java

```
public class ArticleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @BindView(R.id.drawer_layout)
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    @BindView(R.id.articles_view_pager)
    ViewPager articlesViewPager;
    @BindView(R.id.constraint_head_layout)
    CoordinatorLayout constraintHeadLayout;
    private ArticleAdapter articleAdapter;
    private List<List<Articles>> articlesList = null;
    private List<Articles> articlesListChild = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Articles> articlesListChildNew = new ArrayList<>();
    SessionManager session;
    Utils utils;
    final static int MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    int userIdLoggedIn;
    LsArticlesSharedPreference lsArticlesSharedPreference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.bringToFront();

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
            String userId = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);
            userIdLoggedIn = Integer.valueOf(userId);
        } else {
            userIdLoggedIn = 1000;
        }
        utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());

        String storedTime = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("lastUsedDate", "");
        System.out.println("lastUsedDate : " + storedTime);

        if (utils.isNetworkAvailable()) {
            insertData();
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            toggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            articleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), articlesListChild, userIdLoggedIn);
            toggle.syncState();
            clickListeners();
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            Intent noInternetIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoInternetActivity.class);
            startActivity(noInternetIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            finishAffinity();
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                articleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                insertData();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    public void clickListeners() {

    }

    private void insertData() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), OverlayService.class);
        startService(intent);
        final SweetAlertDialog pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(ArticleActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
        pDialog.getProgressHelper().setBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        pDialog.setTitleText("Loading");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
        Api.getClient().getHomeScreenContents(userIdLoggedIn, new Callback<ArticlesResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ArticlesResponse articlesResponse, Response response) {
                articlesList = articlesResponse.getHomeScreenData();
                if (!articlesList.isEmpty()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < articlesList.size(); i++) {
                        articlesListChildNew = articlesList.get(i);
                        articlesListChild.addAll(articlesListChildNew);
                    }
                    articleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), articlesList, articlesListChild, userIdLoggedIn, toolbar);
                    articlesViewPager.setAdapter(articleAdapter);
                    articleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                } else {
                    List<Articles> savedArticles = lsArticlesSharedPreference.getFavorites(getApplicationContext());
                    if (!savedArticles.isEmpty()) {
                        articleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), articlesList, savedArticles, userIdLoggedIn, toolbar);
                        articlesViewPager.setAdapter(articleAdapter);
                        articleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        Api.getClient().getAllArticles(new Callback<AllArticlesResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void success(AllArticlesResponse allArticlesResponse, Response response) {
                                articlesListChild = allArticlesResponse.getArticles();
                                articleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), articlesList, articlesListChild, userIdLoggedIn, toolbar);
                                articlesViewPager.setAdapter(articleAdapter);
                                articleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            };

                            @Override
                            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                                Log.e("articlesData", error.toString());
                            }
                        });
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(ArticleActivity.this, "There was some error fetching the data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Provide code of activity/fragment where you use the adapter.

Comment: @Yamko i have added the activity code in the question, kindly have a look.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue reason:**

You face this issue because the viewpager preload fragments in background. It means that when you see 3rd fragment, the viewpager is instantiating 4th. Due to this workflow your timer for 3rd screen is cancelled and timer for 4th screen is started. Check out this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) to understand what is going on.

**Solution:**

I would do next:

1. Then set page change listener for your adapter. [How to do it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager#addonadapterchangelistener)
2. In this listener you can get current page and start timer for this page (and cancel timer for previously visible page).
3. You don't need to call `startTimer()` method when you instantiate item in `instantiateItem()` method.